# Find Minimum M such that Product of M and a given N should only contain 1 and 0

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, pseudocode

Given a number N, we have to find the minimum positive integer M such that the product of M and N contains only 1 or 0.

Example: If N equals to 3, then the M shall be 37 since the result of 3*37=111, and 111 only contains 1s.

I can think of brute force solution but that's inefficient. Can anyone suggest a good approach for this problem?

Comment: instead of looking for M and checking if the result contains 0 or 1; given N, define a possible value for the product and then check if result%N = 0, which means M is and integer and it is result/N.

Comment: result will always be >= N

Comment: @RafaelLucena  can you provide an example. I'm getting that will require all combinations of 0 and 1. I might have understood wrongly

Comment: Yes, you must try all possible combinations of 0 and 1 until you find a valid M. it is much better than try different M's until you find a valid result. you'll need less iterations